# responsive step bar, vertical for desktop, horizontal for mobile. How?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, progress-bar

in desktop version we have left column (with vertical steps), and right column.
in the mobile version the left column ends up above.
That being said, I would like the mobile version to show the 4 steps horizontally.

but as I did it doesn't work. I do not understand why

anyone can solve?

```html
<div class="row">
<div class="col-lg-4 col-md-5 col-sm-12 blue">
<div class="p-2">
                
<div class="row">
<div class="col-3 col-sm-12">step 1</div>
<div class="col-3 col-sm-12">step 2</div> 
<div class="col-3 col-sm-12">step 3</div> 
<div class="col-3 col-sm-12">step 4</div>   
</div>


</div>
</div>

<div class="col-lg-8 col-md-7 col-sm-12 bg_blue white">
<div class="text-center p-5">
<h1 class="pt-5">Simulator</h1>
<h2>Sei già associato a?</h2>
<div class="m-5">
<button action="" type="button" class="btn round btn-outline-light btn-lg">SÌ</button>
<button type="button" class="btn round btn-outline-light btn-lg">NO</button>
</div>
</div>
</div>


</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

From what I understood, you are trying to make the view of steps

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col-3 col-sm-12">step 1</div>
<div class="col-3 col-sm-12">step 2</div> 
<div class="col-3 col-sm-12">step 3</div> 
<div class="col-3 col-sm-12">step 4</div>   
</div>
```

horizontal, 
The proper way for that would be

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col-12 col-sm-3">step 1</div>
<div class="col-12 col-sm-3">step 2</div> 
<div class="col-12 col-sm-3">step 3</div> 
<div class="col-12 col-sm-3">step 4</div>   
</div>
```

Good luck